# In which case I have to set super() when I create a constructor?

Tags: kotlin, super

I don't understand when I create a constructor, sometimes I have to write this

```
constructor(...):super(){}
```

Do you have an example to understand?

Comment: And it's because the class has a supertype with a constructor. But you might wanna look into primary constructors with an init block rather than secondary ones.

Comment: This is case when parent class constructor should be called, so parent class have constructor which call is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the class `Bar`:

```
open class Foo(val i: Int)

class Bar: Foo {
    constructor(i: Int): super(i)
}
```

Since it has no primary constructor the secondary constructor needs to invoke the constructor of the class it is derived from (which is `Foo`).

> If the class has no primary constructor, then each secondary
>   constructor has to initialize the base type using the super keyword,
>   or to delegate to another constructor which does that. ([Source](http://%3E%20If%20the%20class%20has%20no%20primary%20constructor,%20then%20each%20secondary%20%3E%20constructor%20has%20to%20initialize%20the%20base%20type%20using%20the%20super%20keyword,%20%3E%20or%20to%20delegate%20to%20another%20constructor%20which%20does%20that.))

In this particular case using a primary constructor instead would be the better way though:

```
class Bar(i: Int): Foo(i)
```

> If the derived class has a primary constructor, the base class can
>   (and must) be initialized right there, using the parameters of the
>   primary constructor. ([Source](http://%3E%20If%20the%20class%20has%20no%20primary%20constructor,%20then%20each%20secondary%20%3E%20constructor%20has%20to%20initialize%20the%20base%20type%20using%20the%20super%20keyword,%20%3E%20or%20to%20delegate%20to%20another%20constructor%20which%20does%20that.))